# iOS firebase-database query

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have array of `events`. For every *event*, there's an `artist` with `id="?"`. One artist id could be found in x events. I want to find all events that have artist with given id.

So far I tried with:

```
[[[[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"events"] 
                                       queryOrderedByChild:@"artist"] 
                                       queryEqualToValue:artist.uid 
                                       childKey:@"id"] 
    observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue 
    withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    }
];
```

But I'm doing something wrong. Picture below shows the hierarchy.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`queryEqualToValue:artist.uid` doesn't do what you think. It returns (the) record(s) whose VALUE is equal to `artist.uid`. That means if `artist.uid` is `1`, this will return the record whose value is `1`. Not the record that has an ID field whose value is15. The record whose ENTIRE VALUE is `1`. As in, the record must not be an object, it would have to be an actual number with that value.

Firebase does not provide a "where" mechanism, one that would allow you to query artists where some field is equal to some value. This function call name is a little confusing, but it is not meant for this purpose. If you wanted to achieve what you were doing, you would need to restructure your data such that the ID of the artist was part of the actual ref, such as:

```
/events:
    /by-artist:
        /1:
            /0: { event details... }
```

That is, you would need the artist ID to be part of your actual path structure, allowing you to retrieve `/events/by-artist/ARTISTID/EVENTID`. Standard practice in Firebase would be to store main event data in a master collection, like `/events/EVENTID`, and then a collection of IDs in the sub-collections. This would prevent you from having to double-update multiple locations if the data was changed.